# How do I automatically sync all videos I record with my android phone to my desktop?

Tags: video, sync, android, google-plus

I record a lot of short videos with my Android phone, and I would like to know the most convenient way to keep them synced with a folder in my desktop (OSX). I automatically sync my media from my phone to my Google+ account, but I don't want to have to select these files manually and download them every time I want a local copy.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Leaving open because the question involves an Android device *communicating with a computer*.

Comment: Have you considered Dropbox?

Comment: I believe that [Picasa](https://picasa.google.com/) for Mac has a syncing feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Dropbox in both of them. In the Android equipment enable the option that automatically uploads pictures/videos whenever is on wifi.

Answer (score 1):

There are many [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full&hl=en) that will synchronise files on a schedule or trigger (for example sync when connected to this wifi ssid and when charging).

You will need to provide a way for your phone to talk to your desktop. I can see that ssh or CIFS would do fine.